# fetch the location in github where new file is uploaded

Tags: bash, git, jenkins, github

I got a Github repository which has got few sub-folders in it.
The structure looks like,

```
root
|__ sub1
    |__child1
       |___ file1.txt
|__ sub2
|__ sub3
```

when file1.txt is uploaded, I need to know the complete path where is uploaded.
I am using a bash script in Jenkins to do some processing on these files.
How to get the location where the file is uploaded?

Comment: Github is not like a big file server, where each of your files has some "complete path" that you could access. Think of it more like a database - you've told it to store something on your behalf, and can ask it to give that back to you in various ways. In fact, even locally your git repository is _already_ a database, and what you upload to Github is objects in that database. If you want to fetch something from Github programmatically, there are various ways to do that, depending what you are actually trying to achieve, but without more details it's hard to be more specific than that.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure on why you would do this :) but....

You would git clone the repo on to your Jenkins node using and `checkout` step and then using `find` in an `sh` step to get the path `find . -name file1.txt`

something like (totally untested and totally not production code)

```
  pipeline {
  agent { label 'master' }
  stages {
     stage("Find File 1") {
        steps {
          checkout([\$class: 'GitSCM',
              branches: [[name: '*/master']],
              doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
              extensions: [[\$class: 'CleanCheckout']],
              submoduleCfg: [],
              userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'MY GIT KEY', url: 'git@github.com:MY_REPO.git']]
          ])

          sh "find . -name file1.txt"
        }
     }
  }
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, after raising this question I realized that. Got similar code working..